# How to stop the Message driven adapter dynamically to stop receiving messages?

Tags: jms, spring-integration

```
   <control-bus input-channel ="inboundChannel/>
    <channel id ="inboundChannel"/>
    <message-driven-channel-adapter id="inAQueue" channel="inboundChannel" 
    auto-startup="false" container="DefaultContainer"/>
    <service-activator input-channel="inboundChannel" ref="Something" 
    method="abc"/>
```

inboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("@inAQueue.stop()").build();

inboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("@inAQueue.start()").build());

```
But my service activator class receive this message and throws class cast exception that string can not be cast to jmstextMessage.
```

And I'm not sure if i am trying it in correct manner or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 subscribers on `inboundChannel` - the message-driven adapter and the control-bus. Messages will be distributed in round-robin fashion.

The control bus should subscribe to its own channel, to which the control message is sent.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell . It worked.
But my msgs are being read in speedy manner.
I  need to stop it down so that I can check if after stopping the adapter and again starting the next message is received and no msg lost occur.